# How to update multiple Pis at once?

Tags: raspbian, update, ubuntu, networking

Is there a way to update multiple Raspberry Pi machines at the same time? Would it be possible to update them from a single copy of the image on the central Ubuntu PC server so that the download takes place only once?

The amount of Pis is 40.

Comment: can you connect with ethernet/wifi? then just script an ssh call to each, ssh pi@ip.address command

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at Andrew Mulholland's work on Raspi-LTSP which uses a centralised controller for multiple Pis. It essentially uses the Pi as clients to connect to the central 'server' which can be a laptop or desktop machine. http://pi.gbaman.info/?p=256

Answer (score 2):

Since the Pi boots from an SD card, you need either to update 40 cards using 'dd' to copy an image from your Ubuntu server, or use a bootable image like  http://elinux.org/RPi_U-Boot that will pull the rest of the configuration from a TFTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mean to revive a dead question, but I've been using Ansible to great effect. You can take a look at https://github.com/heisters/node-omxplayer-sync-devops to see how I'm approaching it. It's nice because it just uses SSH, and doesn't require a client install on the pis.

Comment: How does it address the requirement of a single download?

Comment: The single download requirement is a little unclear to me. However, if there's a specific file you only want to download once, you can download it to the local machine and then copy it to the clients. I used to do something similar for installing the latest omxplayer: https://github.com/heisters/node-omxplayer-sync-devops/blob/master/roles/player/tasks/main.yml#L11-L22

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do as they do in most companies to manage a large amount of machines / a cluster / ... and use Puppet/Chef

[Here](http://blog.csanchez.org/2014/01/23/installing-puppet-3-in-a-beaglebone-or-raspberry-pi/) is an article on how to install it.

Comment: This is pretty similar to something like Ansible. Just for context rather than criticism, the reason I went with Ansible over Puppet or Chef is that it's a lot easier to get running on both the clients and the server. On the clients, the only dependency is SSH. I think you may sacrifice some speed and/or features for that ease of install, so Ansible may not be right in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dedicated over-the-air software updater to get safety (rollback in case of any failure) as well as control (deploy to groups, get status & logs, etc). Mender supports Raspbian updates: https://hub.mender.io/t/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-b-raspbian