# Is it possible to update SD card image over network

Tags: raspbian, networking, sd-card

Apologies for my ignorance!
I have few Raspberry Pi's in a network attached to a server and every time I make changes to the image I have to write image to all the SD cards again, can that be automated to update automatically from a network share.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Maybe this helps: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24445/update-40-pis-at-once

Comment: There's a lot of ways to do this if you want to update a mounted *filesystem*, which would be the sane and normal way.  However, if instead you want to re-write the entire image on the card then you either have to move the rootfs to RAM so you can unmount the partitions on the SD card (which if you are capable of this, you'd prefer the sane and normal method since this idea is crazy) or you have to take it out and do it on a normal computer.  Which is also a bit wacky, but to each their own.

Answer (score 0):

One way this could be achieved is by using the u-boot bootloader. U-boot can both check remote servers for updates, and write updates to flash. There are plenty of guides googleable on how to set up uboot for a Raspi, e.g.:

http://arrizza.org/wiki/index.php/RPI_U-boot

Once booting from u-boot, you can write a u-boot script to check a tftp server or similar for an update, and write it to flash if available, before automatically rebooting. Some scripting example and guides can be found at:

http://wiki.lemaker.org/Building_u-boot,_script.bin_and_linux-kernel